# Best Practice for sharing tables across applications

Tags: mysql

We have a single MySQL instance running in our small office.  We have 3 different applications that are all using the db as their backing store.  A single schema has ALL the tables for all three applications.  All of the applications use some common tables (e.g. tbl_users, tbl_facilities, etc.).  I've been using an application prefix for schema objects to visually separate them from the other applications object, for example:

- foo_tbl_settings
- foo_tbl_orders
- foo_vw_recent_orders
- doof_tbl_settings
- doff_vw_parts

I've never been satisfied with this, it always felt like i should be using separate schemas; one for each logical application then a shared schema for shared objects (user table, etc.)

Sharing common tables is very important and I don't want to give it up.

I've done a little googling for this topic but not found anything that really explained if this was a good practice or not.  I was hoping some of you pros could advise me on the best practices for a situation like mine.

Comment: `foo_tbl_settings` translates into `foo.tbl_settings` so naturally...

Comment: I agree, but what are you suggesting?  That I do use separate schemas?

Comment: The usage of those prefixes suggests that a clean separation exists but I didn't post an answer because I didn't want to elaborate on the details :)

Comment: Yeah, they do and I'd sure like to use them like that! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, sharing tables is not a very good behavior.

But if you really need that you can create different schema for every application and create a common schema shared_schema for example.

The common schema can have the shared tables.

Then in every application schema you can create [mysql views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) for every table you want to connect from the shared schema. You can name every view by the the name you need in this schema.
Now you can have tables described with different names.

Comment: Thanks for the info - "sharing tables is not a very good behavior" - can you elaborate on this a bit?  I'm not disagreeing, but would like to know what the main reasons for it being a bad idea are.

Comment: This may lead to inconsistent state for example: if you are a web developer ruby on rails for example, there may be some callbacks are executed from your server after delete a record to clean some data or make some business logic. If a record is deleted from another application then the other applications won't be notified because this is handled from your ruby code.\

Comment: I understand your example, however it doesn't apply to the tables that we will be sharing.  We are actually wanting to share VERY few tables, in fact the only ones I can think of at this time are the _user, _user_roles and _roles tables.  Client applications don't delete the records in these tables and we don't have triggers setup or anything that would cause cascading changes.  Are there any other reasons (performance, ease of administration, etc.) that make sharing tables across schemas a bad idea?

Comment: I think for your case there isn't a problem. Please update me if you faced any problems.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, unless there is a compelling reason to share one DB, could you not just have one DB per application?

You've said they 'share' tables, but then you've described table names with different names, suggesting that whilst they share the same structure they don't actually share the data.
Unless I'm misinterpreting things I'd suggest having one DB per application. This would also then allow you to move the DB and application to a new location without having to de-couple it from the other applications on the server.

Comment: I may not have been clear: The applications share the same data that is in some shared tables.  So it's that we have tables that are similar, it's that we have tables that actually have shared data (e.g. user account data)